# Fibonacci sequence recursive method

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
def fib(x, y, length, fibNum=None):
        if fibNum == None:
           fibNum = []
        while length > 0:
          z = x+y
          x = y
          y = z
          fibNum.append(z)
          length = length-1
          fib(x, y, length, fibNum=fibNum)

print(fib(0,1,10))
```

If I print it I get the result = None. Does anyone have an idea, what the mistake is?

Comment: You did not return anything, it does return None by default.

Comment: Get familiar with return statement

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement `fib` would be as a recursive lambda function, by following its [math definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number),
and then you could make a wrapper function which makes a list of the Fibonacci numbers ranging from `x` to `y`. (E.g. `x = 0, y = 10` makes a list of the first `10` Fibonacci numbers). Finally, the result of this function can be printed.

```
fib = lambda n: n if n <= 1 else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

This lambda is equivalent to the following `fib` function:

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1: 
        return n
    else: 
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def fib_wrapper(x, y):
    return [fib(i) for i in range(x, y)]

print(fib_wrapper(0, 10))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score -1):

as the comments say, u did not return anything.
if you just want Fibounachis , then just try this:

```
def fib(k):
    fib    = []
    if k == 1:
        fib.append(1)
    elif k == 2:
        fib.append(1)
        fib.append(1)
    elif k == 3:
        fib.append(1)
        fib.append(1)
        fib.append(2)
    else:
        fib.append(1)
        fib.append(1)
        fib.append(2)
        while(fib[-1] <= k):
            fib.append(fib[-1] + fib[-2])
    return fib
```

Comment: Rewriting the code without pointing the mistake is not helping OP

Comment: i am really really not agree with you, any way thnx

Comment: I find the result of this code surprising. I would expect k to mean the number of fib numbers, or (still a bit surprising) max fib number. Instead, we get fib numbers and the last one can be greater than k. Example `fib(10) == [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]`. The OP expected the number of elements.

Comment: This is exactly why I think rewriting a full code is not helping OP. Just pointing out his mistake with return would be cool. And then he can do whatever he wants with the method.

Comment: i really appreciate your attention both,but just let's see what he needs. not what we want. peace